# RefelectionException in Illuminate Container.php. Class Injection does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I was just importing this Lumen project from my local machine to an Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox. Both exact same code.

I've tried composer update, composer install. Also from other kind of simillar questions I've added this to the composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
            "app/Library/recaptchalib.php",
            "app/Library/function.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
        "database/"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php" //added this
    ]
},
```

This is the full error log

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class injection does not exist

in /var/www/lumen_app_test/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php line 741
at ReflectionClass->__construct('injection') in Container.php line 741
at Container->build('injection', array()) in Container.php line 631
at Container->make('injection', array()) in Application.php line 447
at Application->make('injection') in Pipeline.php line 123
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1439
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('injection', 'App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware', 'App\Http\Middleware\AssetVersionMiddleware'), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1284
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index', 'middleware' => array('injection', 'language', 'asset_version')), array())) in Application.php line 1207
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1439
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies', 'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse', 'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession', 'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession'), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1213
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in Application.php line 1153
at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 29
```

The thing that made me confuse it that this app runs with no problem in my other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied a middleware called `injection` anywhere? Or is it in the constructor of your `HomeController`? Looks like the container is looking for the definition of that middleware but can't find it (it would usually go in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

If all else fails, delete `/vendor` and then run `composer update` to get a fresh copy of everything.